# Displaying info of a database in a form to persist in another database Php-Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entitymanager

I have 2 databases default database and customer database twice well-configured on `doctrine.yaml`! I want to display on a form the information of the table `Article` which come from customer database to fill the entity Demandes of the default database and persist it afterwards. The two Entity are linked by a foreign key (`idArticle` in Demandes) but I can suppress it if necessary.

But the problem is that I always have the error

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Main\Article or null", "instance
> of App\Entity\Customer\Article" given. or another error like The class
> 'App\Entity\Main\Demandes' was not found in the chain configured
> namespaces App\Entity\Customer

How can I do for doing Symfony understand I just want to fill the entity Demandes with the information Article?

```
->add('idArticle', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => 'App\Entity\Customer\Article',
    'mapped' => true,
    'em' => $options['customer_entity_manager'],
    'choice_label' => 'idArticle'

])
```

And my controller

```
$customerEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer');
$demande = new Demandes();
$demande->setTypeDai("Article");
$demande->setDate(new \DateTime());
$form = $this->createForm(DemandesTypeArticles::class, $demande, [
    'customer_entity_manager' => $customerEntityManager
]);
$form->handleRequest($request);
dump($demande);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
    $entityManager->persist($demande);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

Comment: The `EntityType::class` form field tries to resolve the submitted form value with the help of Doctrine to an ENTITY and not to an INTEGER id even if an integer id is used in the database anyway. To get the integer id value only, you can use [`ChoiceType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)...

Comment: Hum ... Ok but how the choiceType can recognize I want to display the information of my article table ? Because it doesn't accept 'em' annotation ... Maybe you would like me to do query builder ? I will try thanks for the information :)

Comment: _display the information of my article table_ WHAT information of the article table should be displayed WHERE? What is displayed of your choices is what you specify in the `choice_label` option which can also be a property path. _Maybe you would like me to do query builder ?_ You can either fetch all `Article` Entities with the Repository method `findAll` or you can use a query builder. Then set the fetched Entity objects array as the `choices` option of the `ChoiceType`.

Comment: For the first question, for the moment I just try to display the number or entities in my table Article. But in the future I would like to add another property of my entity Article. So for the moment I try findAll method but I got the error The option "choices" with value Closure is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable"... I don't understand this problem ^^ You have an idea ?

Comment: ->add('idArticle', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => function (ArticleRepository $art){
                    return  $choices = $art->findAll();
                },
                'mapped' => true,

            ])

Comment: I posted an answer, just comment if you still have trouble...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChoiceType::class` like shown in the following Code:

```php
class DemandesTypeArticles extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->em = $em; // Pass 'EntityManager' as Service argument.
    }

    // ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void {

        $articles = $this->em->getRepository(Article::Class)->findAll();

        $arctileChoices = [];
        foreach($articles as $article) {
            $label = 'Title: '.$article->getTitle().'; Id: '.$article->getId(); // Change how article choice label showed get rendert.
            $arctileChoices[$label] = $article->getId();
        }

        $builder
            // ...
            ->add('idArticle', ChoiceType::class, [
                'mapped' => true, // Is true by default.
                'choices' => $articleChoices,
            ])

        ;
    }

    // ...configureOptions and stuff
}
```

Comment: Ah I don't know We can do a list like this with the choice_label but I still have the problem of inserting this informations in my table Demandes of the other table because it throws me this error : "The class 'App\Entity\Customer\Article' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Main" !

Comment: Come on Goulashoup you can do it it's my last internship problem if you resolve it I will write a thanks sentence for you in my internship report ^^

Comment: I edited my answer, who have to change the mapping so that `articleId` is NOT an association but just a table with unique integers. Everytime you want the `Article` of a `Demande`, you have to fetch it manually using the value of the `$articleId` property...

Comment: Ok I'm close of the answer but still one problem ! I have done the same thing as you but I have gone throught the articleRepository to get all the Article so my form is appearishing ! I only use the getIdArticle so I got integers ! And error comign saying : "Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Main\Article or null", "int" given." ! I don't know how to put an object instead of integers ...

Comment: I think it's normal because the foreign key I put in Entity Demandes "fkArticles" ask for an object ^^'

Comment: It get's on my nerve I have tried all I can and the only result : The class 'App\Entity\Customer\Article' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Main ... Please somebody ^^